# Extending wall to ceiling with no studs/joist to anchor to

Tags: drywall, walls, ceiling

I have a question for a little project I have in mind. If you take a look at the picture below you can see that between my bedroom and my bathroom there is only a separating wall and no doors. I would like to extend the wall above the separating wall and the closet wall, up to the ceiling (see dotted line), install a door and finally have some privacy when I use the bathroom :)

[image]

Unfortunately the joists above the ceiling run parallel to the wall I intend to build and are not aligned to it (i.e. no joist right above it). What should I do? Should I open the ceiling and add joists/studs/framing to attach the wall to? Or would it be ok to simply create a frame below the ceiling and anchor it to the drywall? (it would be anchored to studs only below and on the left side)

Regardless of how I anchor the wall to the ceiling this is what I was originally thinking of doing

[image: Option 1]

But from some of the comments it looks like I should instead run studs around the door all the way to the ceiling. Something like this:

[image: Option 2]

Is this a preferable option?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Probably just adding the door would be enough.  Do not just use drywall to support/hold anything heavy, that you do not want falling on your foot.

Comment: Do you use wood or metal joists? To properly frame the door, need to know if the height of "closet wall" and "separating wall" is the same. Check with level. Is the door taller than this height? Width-wise, does the door (and frame) fit in the opening between the walls? How much margin is there? Is there space to fit a vertical joist from floor to ceiling on both sides of the door frame for structural integrity?

Comment: I mean, when there is a door, it can get slammed. So you need vertical joists on either side of the door to make the whole wall structurally sound. If that doesn't fit, may need a narrower door. If that's not possible, a horizontal joist between left and right walls over the whole width of the room (not just the width of the door) may be a flimsier but acceptable option.

Comment: Assuming North America, vertical sticks of lumber are studs. Lumber across the top of the door is a header. Horizontal sticks in the floor are joists. Angled sticks in the roof are rafters or components of a truss. So, the OP should have very solid studs on the hinge side of the door, reasonably solid studs on the strike side, and a solid header to tie the two walls together. Personally, I’m sitting on the fence about running studs to the ceiling versus tying the walls together with a good header. Definitely remove corner bead to give room to bed tape.

Comment: @bobflux: it's wood joist and yes the closet and the separating wall has the same height. The door is not taller than this height. The door and its frame should fit in the opening (provided that I remove drywall from the sides) with enough margin to fit vertical studs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this were my project I would run 2x4"s on the ceiling perpendicular to the existing separating walls and tie into those 2x4's for the wall you want to finish. When the wall is built up to the ceiling I would then add a new ceiling to cover the new 2x4"s. You did not say if your bathroom has a shower or just a sink and toilet. Since you are closing in the  existing bathroom, you could add a door, redo the bath7" by adding a 36" shower if you have the room. I had a complete bathroom in a  4x7 foot area in the primary bedroom in my last house.  Tight for space but do-able.

Comment: Good suggestion!  Adding perpendicular 2x4s between the joists (as opposed to hung on the ceiling) is usually called **blocking** and this technique can be found in any book about framing.

Comment: Yes, I had not thought of this. Though to me it looks like more work than opening the ceiling and add studs/framing to attach my wall to. In any case no need to add a shower (one is already present in a smaller room behind the closet)