# Remove metal corner bead when extending wall

Tags: drywall, walls, corner-bead

This is related to another question I asked in this forum (see [Extending wall to ceiling with no studs/joist to anchor to](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/235693/extending-wall-to-ceiling-with-no-studs-joist-to-anchor-to)).

As you can see in the picture below I intend to extend the wall up to the ceiling. To do that I'll have to butt new drywall to existing drywall in the closet and in the separating wall (whose corners are protected by metal corner beads)

Should I remove those corner beads before proceeding or is it usually ok to leave them for this kind of project?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably, the ends of the separating wall is wrapped in drywall. You'll want to remove that piece as you attach your studs to frame up for the door you're installing. If you don't, you may have a hard time getting the studs placed square to the wall. In the process of removing those little strips of drywall, the corner beads will come off anyway.

Additionally, if you were to leave the corner beads, you'd end up with ridges in the finished drywall. The corner bead does tend to stick out a bit from the wall. You don't notice because they're feathered in by running the joint compound 12" or so back from the corner.

Comment: Yes, even with removing the beads you'll have a thickened area from the previous tape job. You want to minimize that.